# Laravel 5 Search dos`t functioning

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5

I`m new to the laravel 5.4 and need to created multi attribute search.
before i search.
[image]

After the search as same the results before.
[image]

Here is my controller.

```
 public function search_code(Request $request){
    $query = $request->search;
    $queryType = $request->institute; // 'id' or 'name'
    $items = DB::table('registerdetails');        

    if($queryType == 'id'){
      $items = $items->where('id', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
    }
    if($queryType == 'full_name'){
      $items = $items->where('full_name', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
    }
   $items = $items->get();

    return view('registeredusers.index')->with('items',$items);

            }
```

Here is my view.

```
 <form action="search" method="post" class="form-inline">          
   <select name="institute" id="institute">
    <option selected="selected" value="Trainee Id">Trainee Id</option>
    <option value="Trainee Name">Trainee Name</option>
  <label for="Search">Name</label>
</select>  
       <input type="text" name="search" /><br>
       <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token" />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
       </form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-body">

                  <table class="table table-striped">
                  <thead>

                    <th>Full Name</th>
                    <th>Name with initials</th>
                    <th>National ID Number</th>
                    <th>Date Of Birth</th>

                  </thead>

                  <tbody>
                    @foreach($items as $item)

                     <tr>

                  <td>{{ $item->full_name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->name_with_initials }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->nic_no }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->date_of_birth }}</td>
              </tr>
                    @endforeach

                  </tbody>

          </table>

            </div>
        </div>
```

In the route i wrote ,i though problem is in route here are the two routs

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::resource('/userregister', 'UserRegisterController');

});
Route::post('search', 'UserRegisterController@search_code');
```

Can anyone suggest me to get results by searching this?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: search not working.as an example if i enter id 1 both results show but they are in two different ids

Comment: Is it showing all the records now?

Comment: yes of course thats why i said it is not functioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the values in select dropdown like below

```
<select name="institute" id="institute">
  <option selected="selected" value="id">Trainee Id</option>
  <option value="full_name">Trainee Name</option>
  <label for="Search">Name</label>
</select>
```

One more suggestion,
If only one condition is possible then use 'else if' like below,

```
if($queryType == 'id'){
  $items = $items->where('id', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
}
else if($queryType == 'full_name'){
  $items = $items->where('full_name', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
}
```